# Leaking AC duct

Tags: air-conditioning, water-damage

I bought a house back in March and haven't noticed any issues with the house until last week. About a week after Henri made landfall in CT, I noticed the carpet in the basement was a little damp. Upon inspecting the AC duct above the carpet I noticed a very small amount of condensation and even a water drop trickling down the side of the duct. After putting a bucket below the duct, either the "leak" has stopped or the amount falling into the bucket is so slight that it evaporates before I ever notice it collecting (I think it is the former as I no longer see any condensation on the duct). I ran the water from every spout in the house for a prolonged period of time and that made no difference in the water collection on the duct, so I feel confident I can rule out the water pipes as the problem. Does anyone have any insight/suggestions on what is to be done here? As the problem has stopped (as far as I can tell), I doubt turning off the AC will do anything, but I am rather unsure what I should do. Note it has been very hot/humid here recently and I mentioned the storm that hit us, because although I did check the basement for flooding during and after the storm, the amount of water on the carpet was very slight and I only noticed the problem because I was barefoot in the basement.

Attaching images of the air duct and the water condensation:
[Water drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoELw.png)

[image: Water drop]
[image: Basement with air duct]

[image: Close up image of water collection]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cold air blowing inside a metal tube` plus `very hot humid weather` equals `condensation`. It's a part of life on planet Earth.

You could insulate the duct work, as that will help prevent the warm moist air from coming in contact with the cold metal, but if it takes tropical storm/hurricane levels of humidity to cause condensation, it may well not be worth the effort to prevent a bit of condensation every few years.